# How can I use XFLR5 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: fixed-wing, simulators, aircraft

I'm working on an aircraft project and I need XFLR5 to decide on a suitable airfoil. However, I can see that it is only available in Ubuntu 18.04. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.
What can I do about this? Is there a way to get around it or an alternative solution?

Comment: Most programs don't rely so heavily on version-specific features that they need to be used only with that version. I'd be surprised if it didn't run (maybe with a few package changes) on U20.04. Have you tried?

Comment: I tried looking for the package but I couldn't find it

Comment: The xflr5 download page provides build instructions - they recommend downloading an IDE but command line may be suitable with enough experience. The instructions appear straightforward enough, and you can build for whichever ubuntu version you'd like. http://www.xflr5.tech/xflr5.htm